# Wicket - Ajax form submit from one list to another

Tags: java, ajax, forms, wicket

In wicket, how would I create the following behavior: have a ListMultipleChoice on the left that takes in data models from the server, a button in the middle that would take the selected components from that list and insert them into another list on the right using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

That's called a Palette in Wicket (and other places) and there is a Wicket Component that does this. See [JavaDocs](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/form/palette/Palette.html) for more information